# ls command is not resulting file timestamp instead it is just displaying only year

Tags: ls, command, output

While I am running ls command on IBM AIX machine, sometimes it is resulting in only year part of the file timestamp.

For example :
ls -lrt test.txt          0 Apr 28 2020  test.txt
 but sometimes the command is resulting in only year part of the file timestamp.

Can you please help us on how and when this issue occurs in AIX Unix

Comment: Hello sathish. I'm not sure I entirely understand your question (something to do with `ls`?). Please would you provide a real example, and format the command and its response with the {} button so we can see what's computer interaction and what's your explanation surrounding it.

Comment: Do you really get the year displayed for a file created today as well ("Apr 28 2020")?

Comment: when i run ls -lrt test.txt sometimes we get output as 0 Apr 28 2020 test.txt and sometimes we get output as 0 2020 test.txt

Answer (score 0):

This is handled the same way on all UNIX platforms.

If a file is older than 6 months, only the date is shown.

Comment: The file a recent file. Not older than 6 months

Comment: Is the file a file from the future?